# Action Tiles Optional?

Tags: betrayal-legacy

In Betrayal Legacy there are some tiles that are eat and drink. Drink is an action so the question is whether or not these tiles are mandatory when you enter the room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actions such as DRINK are optional. Per the [rulebook](https://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/rules/BLY-Rulebook.pdf), on page 14, you can only choose to do one of each action keyword per turn, so you may have the option to DRINK on one tile -- or to use the DRINK action on an item card, for example.